# Rotating the Graphs in Graph Editor

Tags: graph-editor

I would like to ask a question regarding Curve handling in Graph editor. To ask the question here I have taken a help of an example. In the screenshot, as attached, I would like to rotate the line AM ClockWise (CW) for X axis, centering at A, so that AB can looks like similar to CD of Y axis and vice-a-versa CD to rotate CCW centering at C, so that it looks like similar to AM.
Submitted please for a solution.
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

Select the pivot point keyframe press shift S > Cursor to selected. Change the pivot point mode form "Bounding box center" to "2D Cursor". Then select the keyframes and press R to rotate, click to confirm.

If there is no keyframe where the 2D cursor is supposed to be, you can set its loc coordinates in the side N panel, view tab.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can rotate and translate a selection of points in the graph the same way you do in the 3D viewport.

That being said, it doesn't lock any axes, the keys will move in both X and Y axes:

[image: rotation]

So if you need to keep the variation of value between A and B while making the curve go globally downwards/upwards, you can't rotate it.

What you can do however, is make a new action like you already did, that contains the downward/upward change, overlay it via the NLA editor, and bake the entire result into a new action.

Otherwise, if you don't need to preserve the animation between A and B and just want it to go from A to B, the easiest way is to just delete the keyframes between A and B.